# how to know to define asuitable posterior for bayesian deep learning

Tags: deep-learning, bayesian-deep-learning

I work with model its purpose for classification task in medical image, i want also to estimate uncertainty , so i work with Bayesian technique , i use a pre-trained model for feature extraction and then add Dense Variational layers to make classification , what is the suitable posterior we an define for medical imaging, because when dealing with dense-variational layer we have to define prior and postrior.
and did that right? ue pre-trained for feature extraction and  then add dense variational layer .
my propose for classification and uncertainty
note; i try normal distribution for posterior didnt work well